# Jetson GPIO library missing?

Tags: python, raspberrypi, libraries

Im sure this isn't the right site to ask this but I couldn't find a site specificly for the Jetson Nano board.

Anyway, my issue is that I'm trying to use the GPIO library to spin some motors. When I go to execute the script I have written, I get an error saying

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'RPi'
```

I've imported the library as `GPIO` but the real issue is the library being missing. According to multiple sites I've visited, there's supposed to be a folder at

```
opt/nvidia/
```

named `Jetson-GPIO` but there isn't. Only see '`jetson-io`'... Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Ended up figuring out the issue with trial and error. I ended up having to **reinstall a fresh copy of Jetpack, install the correct `pip`version, and download the `RPi.GPIO`library**, then everything worked!